# Replace escaped double quotes in CSV

Tags: php, string, csv

I am reading content from a csv. I want to replace the single and double quotes from the data. I have tried the following code but is not working.

```
    $resource = fopen($this->csv_file, 'r');
    while (($data = fgetcsv($resource, 10000, ',')) !== false) {
    $custom = $data[10];
    $custom = str_replace('"', 'in',$custom);
    $custom = str_replace("'", 'ft',$custom);
```

$custom has the value of a column from CSV. It seems that double quotes are escaped in CSV using double quotes like `15""x5000'`
How can I do this in PHP?

var_dump is showing `string '15"x5000' Produce Film' (length=22)`
CSV in editor is showing `"Select the product size and enter the quantity|15""x5000' Produce Film"`

Comment: What is `$custom`? Show more code to understand the context.

Comment: It is a column value from csv

Comment: And how does the value get _from_ the CSV, _into_ that variable? If you did that _correctly_, using `fgetcsv`, then you should not have this problem to begin with ...

Comment: I am using fgetcsv

Comment: Show a [mre] of the problem, including the exact source data, the code you've used to read that data and put it into a variable, and the exact contents of the variable as you're currently seeing it. Then we can understand how you got here, and also the data you're trying to do the replacement on. As mentioned, it seems like it's unlikely you'd get this kind of issue if the data is imported correctly, so it could be that the root cause of the issue is elsewhere in your import routine.

Comment: Well that's half of what I asked for... :-). You missed showing us the source data from the CSV (as seen from a text editor, please), and what it looks like when you `var_dump($data[10]);`

Comment: How did it become `15"x5000'-produce-film`, based on the data you've shown from the CSV? fgetcsv doesn't replace spaces with `-`, or remove anything from the text. Did you omit some steps from the code? Anyway, regardless, if we use that value as the input, then your str_replace function works fine - demo; https://3v4l.org/llBBn

Comment: My mistake. There were two fields I copied the other one. Yes, I am breaking the text with '|'. I have updated the question.

Comment: Ok thanks. But there's still no problem with your str_replace code as far as I can see: https://3v4l.org/8VDcC . So it's a bit unclear what the issue is or what you want help with.